# export default not working with react - bug or coders error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component I am trying to simplify. I am removing some functions from the file to put into another folder to help make the code more readable.

this is an example of one of the functions I'm moving,

```js
export default function generatemwapGraphData(items) {
    let total = {
      mwap: 0,
  ..  };
    let count = items.length;
  
    items.forEach((item) => {
      total["mwap"] += item["mwap"] / count;
     ...
    });
  
    let finalData = [];
  
    Object.keys(total).forEach((exp) => {
      finalData.push({
        expression: exp,
        Percentage: +(total[exp] * 100).toFixed(2),
      });
    });
  
    return finalData;
  }
```

Now when I take this function and try to import it like this,

```
import generateExpressionsGraphData from "components/dashboard/Mood/functions/generateExpressionsGraphData"
```

It returns an error of

```
Attempted import error: 'generateExpressionsGraphData' is not exported from 'components/dashboard/Mood/functions/generateExpressionsGraphData' (imported as 'generateExpressionsGraphData').
```

Surely this should be fine?

Thanks

Comment: This should've worked. You should check your file names and file path and see if they are correct.

Comment: please double check the component name and file `generatemwapGraphData` or `generateExpressionsGraphData`

Comment: It is the sdame, just changed it to anonymise it a bit

Comment: Can you create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't exported the function from that file.
Note that if you use **export default** you have to import it like **import something from file** and when you use just *export something* you have to import it in curly braces like **import {something} from file**.
Also check the file name that has to be imported identical.